# How do I put a worksheet inside one slice of pie chart in Tableau?

Tags: bar-chart, pie-chart, tableau-desktop

I have created a piechart based upon some of the relevant statuses of the company e.g. Closed, In Progress etc. Now separately I have created other worksheets with the resolution status count and the clients name. How do I link the relevant slices of pie chart with the sheets?

I have tried from the tooltip but it is inserting the sheet for the whole piechart.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Daremitsu, try click on filter button
[image]

Then click on the country and see the result
[image]